# View Platform Event External Subscribers

Tags: platform-event

I created a platform event, i can able to publish that event to an event bus in salesforce, I can able to subscribe to that event within salesforce and also externally. I can fetch the subscriber details within the salesforce by using a query. 
**But is there anyway that we could fetch or view the list of Subscribers who subscribed to respective Platform event outside salesforce.**

Query I used to fetch subscribers within salesforce

```
SELECT ExternalId, Name, Position,Retries, Status, Tip, Topic, Type
FROM EventBusSubscriber
WHERE Topic='EventName__e'
```

Comment: Currently, there is no way to do that, looks like a candidate for idea exchange

Comment: this is worthy of posting to the Platform Events community that is monitored by the PM: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004gjg